# WCF service call using TAP pattern does not honor WCF binding timeout

Tags: web-services, wcf, timeout, async-await

I'm using Xamarin iOS and the silverlight 3 slsvcutil to generate WCF services for use in a mobile app.  I then create a task based implementation using the Task.Factory.FromAsync so I can use async await against the service call.  In making this call for a lengthy data transmission I'm getting a network timeout exception at 60 seconds even though the WCF binding is set to use 10 minutes, long, but safe.  The code to create the Task is:

```
public Task<byte[]> SyncExAsyncT(int accountId, string accountUsername, byte[] syncData, System.DateTime lastSyncDateUtc, int appVersion, string deviceName, string misc, int modelVersion, string deviceToken)
{
    return Task<byte[]>.Factory.FromAsync((callback, asyncState) =>
        base.Channel.BeginSyncEx(accountId, accountUsername, syncData, lastSyncDateUtc, appVersion, deviceName, misc, modelVersion, deviceToken, callback, asyncState),
        base.Channel.EndSyncEx, null);
}
```

I call the method as expected using `byte[] responseStream = await client.SyncExAsyncT`

How can I control the timeout of this implementation such that I can avoid the network timeout at 60 seconds?

Comment: Are you sure the timeout is coming from WCF and not the underlying data connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see also to these bugs:

```
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25251
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19697
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18029
```

This issue is not fixed since months